# Taylor series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{\log(1+z^2)}{(1-z)\sinh z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I need to find the first 3 terms of the Taylor expansion around $z=0$ of the complex function:

$$f(z)=\frac{\log(1+z^2)}{(1-z)\sinh z}$$

I tried the following way (obviously the radius of convergence is $R=1$ so we can consider $|z|<1$):

$$\log(1+z^2) \sim z^2$$

$$\frac{1}{1-z} \sim 1+z+z^2+z^3$$

$$\sinh z \sim z+\frac{z^3}{6}$$

Then:

$$f(z) \sim (1+z+z^2+z^3)z^2\frac{1}{z+z^3/6}=(1+z+z^2+z^3)z\frac{1}{1+z^2/6} \sim
\\
\sim (z+z^2+z^3)\frac{1}{1+z^2/6} \sim (z+z^2+z^3)(1-z^2/6) \sim
\\
\sim z+z^2+\frac{5}{6}z^3$$

I have neglected the terms $o(z^3)$. This result is not consistent with the solution o the exercise, which is:

$$z+z^2+\frac{z^3}{3}$$

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I notice that $\ln(1+x^2)$ in the numerator and $\sinh z$ in the denominator have a common factor of $z$, which cancels, reducing the effective degree of your expansions of both by one.  Try taking those two to fourth order...  (You may, or may choose not to, expand $1/(1-z)$ to fourth order as well -- you'll get the same result either way because there is no cancellation with this factor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log(1+z^2)=\operatorname{ln}(1+z^2)$, I assume? If so, the first three terms of its Taylor expansion about $z=0$ are $z^2-\frac{z^4}{2}+\frac{z^6}{3}$. The first three terms of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ are $1+z+z^2$ and the first three terms of $\frac{1}{\operatorname{sinh}z}$ are $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360}$

Multiplying the first two:

$$(z^2-\frac{z^4}{2}+\frac{z^6}{3})(1+z+z^2)=z^2+z^3+z^4-\frac{z^4}{2}-\frac{z^5}{2}-\frac{z^6}{2}+\frac{z^6}{3}+\frac{z^7}{3}+\frac{z^8}{3}$$

Now since we want terms of order $3$, we may discard the terms of order $5$ and higher. Multiplying what's left by the first three terms of the last expansion:

$$(z^2+z^3+\frac{z^4}{2})(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7z^3}{360})=z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{7z^5}{360}+z^2-\frac{z^4}{6}+\frac{7z^6}{360}+\frac{z^3}{2}-\frac{z^5}{12}+\frac{7z^7}{720}$$

Discarding the terms of order $4$ and higher, we are left with $z+z^2+\frac{z^3}{2}-\frac{z^3}{6}=z+z^2+\frac{2z^3}{6}=z+z^2+\frac{z^3}{3}$, as required. Your mistake was in not using enough terms from the expansions of $\log(1+z^2)$ and $\frac{1}{\operatorname{sinh}z}$